# Duplicating of records in simple join query

Tags: sql, plsql

Please see Code  below and pictures of expected results

New query of the view gives me same incorrect result

```
            select VW_DAWN_FRIDAY.*, invoice_no  from VW_DAWN_FRIDAY
            inner join cl$invoices 
            on cl$invoices.project_id = VW_DAWN_FRIDAY.project_id

             SELECT DISTINCT VW_Learners_Train_Cost.learner_id,
             VW_Learners_Train_Cost.project_id,
             VW_Learners_Train_Cost.client_name,
             VW_Learners_Train_Cost.FIRST_NAME,
             VW_Learners_Train_Cost.LAST_NAME,
             VW_Learners_Train_Cost.quote_no,
             cl$invoices.total "Invoiced Amt incl VAT",
             cl$invoices.invoice_no
             FROM VW_Learners_Train_Cost
             INNER JOIN cl$invoices
             ON cl$invoices.project_id = VW_Learners_Train_Cost.PROJECT_ID
             AND cl$invoices.client_id = VW_Learners_Train_Cost.client_id
```

Results 
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jiu4.gif)

expected 
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhPXo.gif)

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I want the code to render the expected picture not the results I am getting

Comment: There are different invoice_no in each one, they are not duplicated.. how do you expect us to know which one you want?

Comment: The name is duplicated I check the tables & invoices should be the same

Comment: So where is this invoices comes from? If you want us to help either tell us that, or post the table data

Comment: The project_id is one to one with quote_id if that helps , Not sure how to put invoices data table up or just a few records

Comment: Is there any reason to take just one special invoice? if not, you can just go with row_number over learnerID and take rownum = 1

Comment: Im use one invoice as an example and vw_leaner_train is a view

Comment: And because there are so many invoices thats why its duplicate , if I can get the first invoice per project that be great

Comment: You can either remove `invoice_no` from your `SELECT` clause or do as @Veljko89 suggested - use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) function.

Comment: I need invoice_no thanks

Comment: I have updated the query and still get the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're joining twice, in the second query:

```
ON cl$invoices.project_id = VW_Learners_Train_Cost.PROJECT_ID
AND cl$invoices.client_id = VW_Learners_Train_Cost.client_id
```

Assuming both queries are trying to get the same  (well, similar) output.

Comment: Is that "you don't think it is" or "you've tested that, and it isn't it"?

Comment: I have tested it and I get the same result